# Knowing which tables have columns "a" and "b" using an SQL query

Tags: mysql

I want to get all the tables that have a column called "a" and another column called "b"

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tables.name FROM tables_colums INNER JOIN tables INNER JOIN colums 
ON tables.id = tables_colums.table_id AND colums.id = tables_colums.column_id 
WHERE columns.name = "a" AND columns.name = "b"
```

Comment: Are you asking what table in mysql the column stores the column names?

Comment: Use [24.4 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find metadata in the `information_schema` database. The medadata for columns is stored in the `information_schema.columns` table.

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.columns
where COLUMN_NAME in ('a', 'b')
group by TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
having count(*) = 2
```

If you only want tables from a specific database (schema):

```
select TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.columns
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db'
  and COLUMN_NAME in ('a', 'b')
group by TABLE_NAME
having count(*) = 2
```

[live demo](http://rextester.com/JDGMJI92380)